# Android broadcastreceiver without unregisreting throws runtime error

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I've got a simple broadcast receiver

```
public class OnlineListener extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static final String ONLINE_BROADCAST = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"; 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Log.d("", "Network connectivity change");
//      if (intent.getExtras() != null)
//      {
//          final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
//          final NetworkInfo ni = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
//          if (ni != null && ni.isConnectedOrConnecting())
//          {
//              Toast.makeText(context, "Network " + ni.getTypeName() + " connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//          }
//          else if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE))
//          {
//              Toast.makeText(context, "There's no network connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//          }
//      }
    }
}
```

with everything is commented, and I register through main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    public static OnlineListener onlineListener = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if( onlineListener == null )
            registerOnlineListener();
    }
    public void registerOnlineListener()
    {
        onlineListener = new OnlineListener();
        registerReceiver( onlineListener , new IntentFilter(OnlineListener.ONLINE_BROADCAST));
    }   
}
```

and I get this error

```
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.testservice.OnlineListener: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.testservice.OnlineListener in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.testservice-2.apk]
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1777)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.testservice.OnlineListener in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.testservice-2.apk]
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1768)
11-21 09:27:58.099: E/AndroidRuntime(18036):    ... 10 more
```

on second network change which is when my BR.onreive() is called, some people say that I should unregister my BR, but i need it to always run, as I'll have a service with download queue to be executed whenever the device is online.

What shall I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of registering your BroadcastReceiver in your Activity, register it in your manifest, like so:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.testservice.OnlineListener"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" /> 
    </intent-filter>            
</receiver>
```

Whenever that Action is broadcast, your Receiver will start, at which point you can check the connectivity status and handle your Service accordingly.

Comment: I already have it defined in manifest, I removed it from activity still I got the same error

Comment: I have it registered in manifest as same as you have posted, when lunching the activity it prints "Network connectivity change" which means my BR is working, if i turn on/off wifi the app crash with the posted error

Comment: could it be device issue? I'm using galaxy geo 2.3.3 ginger

Answer (score 0):

I've solved that with code provided [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/)